# When opening a Liquidity Position in UniV3, how my capital is distributed for each tick?

Tags: uniswapv3

Let's say I am opening a liquidity position at ETH/USDC pool.
Price is 1000 and let's say its tick is 1000 arbitrarily
I am opening a liquidity position with range 950-980 and let's say its tick is 950-980 arbitrarily. I am using 1000 USDC.
Then, I know that my 1000 USDC will be distributed to each tick within 950-980. However, How are my USDC distributed for each tick? will my usdc be assigned less on 950'th tick, creating equal liquidity for each tick? or USDC will be equally distributed to each tick, so 950'th tick having more liquidity than other ticks?